# R numeric value: exact or rounded value

Tags: r, floating-point

As [R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) states, the only numbers that can be represented exactly in R’s numeric type are

- integers
- fractions whose denominator is a power of 2

All other numbers are internally rounded to (typically) 53 binary digits accuracy.

Having said that, how to say a given number can be stored exactly in R's numeric type or should be rounded? Or stated differently, how to say a numeric number is the result of a fraction whose denominator is a power of 2 or not?

For example, `0.03125` can be stored excatly since its the result of `1/32` (i.e., denominator is a power of 2)

```
sprintf("%.60f", 1/32)
#[1] "0.031250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: I'm unsure if you want to do this programmatically. If yes, what is the input? `294/511`?

Comment: Btw., an R numeric value is a double-precision floating-point number.

Comment: @Roland please check my edit.

Comment: I'm still unsure if you want to be able to find out with, e.g., pen and paper or if you want R to tell you. Also, given a floating-point number you can't know if it is an exact result. Floating point accuracy is always limited. For your example: `sprintf("%.60f", 1000000000000000/32000000000000001)`.

Comment: @Roland In its simplest form, my question is: if I have a real number, can I store it in R's numeric type exactly or it would inevitably be rounded (and yes, programmatically) ? Hope I could clarify it.

Comment: Thanks for your good example. But we know that I can store this number in R exactly.

Comment: @Ruser: There are two problems interpreting your question. One, we do not know whether you are asking how to write software that would indicate whether or not a given input is representable in R’s numeric type or you are asking how a person could determine on their own whether or not a given real number is representable in R’s numeric type. You should say which.…

Comment: … Two, we do not know what you mean by “have a real number.” Real numbers are not physical objects, so you cannot physically have one. At most, you have some representation of a real number. Is it expressed as an expression of elementary functions? Is it a decimal numeral? Or something else?

Comment: What @EricPostpischil said. But maybe, `library(gmp); as.bigq(1, 3) == as.bigq(1/3)` is what you are looking for?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for your remarks. Of two said interpretations, the first one. As for the second comment, as I said, like my example.

Comment: @Roland Thanks. I should check `as.bigq`

Comment: Theoretically, determining if a decimal numeral is representable in R’s numeric format is simple: If its magnitude equals or exceeds 2^1024, it is not representable. Otherwise, if it is an integer, it is representable iff repeatedly dividing it by 2 until it is odd yields a number less than 2^54. Otherwise, it is representable iff the result of repeatedly multiplying it by 2 until either the result is an integer or 1074 multiplications have been performed is an integer less than 2^54. However, you likely want some easy-to-code test using existing functions, so this is a comment, not an answer.